# rails 3 does not render jquery properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i have https://github.com/tkrotoff/jquery-simplecolorpicker-rails and i have tried https://github.com/tkrotoff/jquery-simplecolorpicker in plain HTML and the plain HTML worked.

I had swapped the code from the HTML to the one in rails but all my jquery functions does not work at all.

```
The file colorselect.js 

    $(function(){
    $('#print_colorpaper').simplecolorpicker();
    });
```

colorpaper.html.erb

```
<%= f.select(:colorpaper, Print::MY_COLORS, :selected => '#fbd75b') %>
```

the only thing i see in rails is the drop down menu which should be transformed into a palette as i see here: http://www.taqisystems.com/fiddle/

my application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.simplecolorpicker.js
//= require jquery.multi-select.js
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

html source of the select:

```
    <select id="print_colorpaper" name="print[colorpaper]"><option value="#7bd148">green</option>
```

Comment: Do you have this in application.css *= require jquery.simplecolorpicker.css

Comment: yes. i have the file included in application.css

 *= require_self
 *= require jquery.simplecolorpicker.css
 *= require_tree .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it working using the following:
Try change in your app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       jQuery('#print_colorpaper').simplecolorpicker();
    });
```

Comment: no it doesn't work, i tried using a test rails app and added twitter bootstrap - it doesn't work.