# jquery rails with twitter bootstrap does not render

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have made some progress here: [rails 3 does not render jquery properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17624371/rails-3-does-not-render-jquery-properly)

With my test application, it works OK but with twitter bootstrap loaded - it does not work and it shows the drop down menu (which should be a palette). I have gone through steps to verify whether the jquery in rails renders the palette properly and this is my implemention to the one with twitter bootstrap.

As written in the post above, i had written the code into application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.simplecolorpicker.js
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require_tree .
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       jQuery('#print_colorpaper').simplecolorpicker();
    });
```

application.css

```
 *= require_self
 *= require jquery.simplecolorpicker.css
 *= require_tree .
```

erb file

```
<%= f.select(:colorpaper, Print::MY_COLORS, :selected => '#ff887c') %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to include css in the end of the file, try this in application.css

`*= require jquery.simplecolorpicker`

Or even put that file in app/assets/stylesheets and `require_tree .` will pick it up automatically.

Comment: It picked up automatically but it does not render the jquery plugin as it should (a dropdown instead of a palette)

I have tried the above but it couldn't render the palette.

Comment: Try also this `//= require jquery.simplecolorpicker` without js in the end. By the way try to find error in console. Keep in mind that rails 4 using turbolinks, you must also add `$(document).on('page:load', $('#print_colorpaper').simplecolorpicker())` in that case

Comment: i had tried with an earlier case (URL in my question) with a test rails app and it doesn't work after adding twitter bootstrap to it.

Developer console doesn't show anything, meaning there are no errors.